# Add a summary row with totals for each clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out how to make this sql select statement, I use `PostgreSQL` database.
Here are my tables :

[image]

I want to add an extra row show the count of customer by gender:

[image]

Could this be done?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And next time try to provide the data in text format as show in my answer that will save us lot of time, because we cant copy/paste from pictures.

Comment: Similar question: [Select rows with subtotals maintaining proper order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990646/1995738)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)(`Postgresql 9.5+`):

```
CREATE TABLE customers(idcust INT, name VARCHAR(100), fkGender INT);
INSERT INTO customers(idcust, name, fkGender)
SELECT 1, 'bob', 3 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'alice', 3  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'mikel', 4;

CREATE TABLE gender(IdGender INT, gender VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO gender(IdGender, gender) VALUES (3, 'male'),(4,'female');

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT CASE WHEN idcust::text IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE idcust::text END AS IdCust,
       CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN name ELSE COUNT(*)::text END AS name,
       CASE WHEN idcust::text IS NULL THEN '' ELSE gender END AS genderName
FROM customers c
JOIN gender g
  ON c.fkGender = g.idGender
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((idcust, name, gender), (gender))
ORDER BY gender DESC, idcust;
```

Output:

[image]

Keep in mind that `idcust` is probably `INT` so to get `Total` in that column you have to cast to text first.

Comment: Only for postgres 9.5.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yup, added note

Answer (score 0):

For version before a 9.5 you can create an aditional column `group_id` and as always be carefull about data type so doesnt mix text and numbers.

**NOTE:** But consider for this kind of things you usually return both `SELECT` separated and join them on the Front End so you can apply proper format/styling

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8da8/18)**

```
SELECT idcust::text, name, gender
FROM 
(
    SELECT 2*fkGender as  group_id,
           idcust::text, name, gender
    FROM customers c
    JOIN gender g
      ON c.fkGender = g.idGender
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2*fkGender + 1 as group_id,
           'Total'::text as idcust,
           COUNT(*)::text as name,
           '' as gender
    FROM  customers c
    GROUP BY group_id, fkGender
) T
ORDER BY group_id, idcust
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| idcust |  name | gender |
|--------|-------|--------|
|      1 |   bob |   male |
|      2 | alice |   male |
|  Total |     2 |        |
|      3 | mikel | female |
|  Total |     1 |        |
```

Comment: thank you Juan for your answer but , for this example we have just two gender male or female but if we have more than two gender  fkgender should be iterated ?

Comment: check my update should work with any number of genders, but as I say in my notes those should be solve in UI